# FDT5 Haxe Compilation Error "Uncaught exception - module.c(124) : Builtin not found : fasthash"

Tags: ide, haxe, fdt, neko

I am a user of FDT5 and getting this very strange Haxe compiler error when using v2.09 of Haxe and v1.8.2 of NekoVM.

"Uncaught exception - module.c(124) : Builtin not found : fasthash"

Can anyone help me resolve this error as can't compile my FDT5 project, as if I compile it directly in Mac OSX Lion. Terminal it does not report any issues.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You may need to setup the path to your Neko installation

FDT 5.5 ships with Neko, but the path to it is not set by default. Because it's not, you may get errors as you mentioned:

[image]

To fix this, go to Preferences>Haxe>Neko VM and point to a Neko installation directory.

### Custom Installation Directory

You can point to a custom installation. Perhaps if you used the standalone installer from the [Haxe website](http://haxe.org/download).

[image: Setting to a custom install directory]

### Using FDT's Neko Installation

For windows you can just point to FDT5>haxe>neko-1.8.2-osx

For OSX, because FDT is a self contained package, you can't naviagate to Neko via the OSX GUI. Instead type in this path, or copy and paste the path from where your Haxe location is set and paste it into the Neko location. Then just change the last directory name to the name of the Neko folder: haxe-2.09-osx -> neko-1.8.2-osx.

[image] 
[image]